# An unknown memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am trying to recreate a simple string class. It's only for exercising purposes. I am getting a run-time error when my code finishes. I am not quite sure,but I think it's a memory leak.

Here's the code:

```
class FITString{
    char *tekst;
public: 
    FITString(char *bla = " "){
        tekst = new char[strlen(bla) + 1];
        strcpy_s(tekst, strlen(bla) + 1, bla);
    }
    ~FITString(){
        delete[] tekst;
        tekst = nullptr;        
    }
    FITString(FITString &original){
        tekst = new char[strlen(original.tekst) + 1];
        strcpy_s(tekst, strlen(original.tekst) + 1, original.tekst);
    }
    FITString operator+ (FITString &drugi){
        char *pomocna = new char[strlen(tekst) + strlen(drugi.tekst) + 1];
        strcpy_s(pomocna, strlen(tekst) + 1, tekst);
        strcat_s(pomocna, strlen(tekst) + strlen(drugi.tekst) + 1, drugi.tekst);
        return pomocna;
    }

    void operator+= (FITString &drugi){
        strcat_s(tekst, strlen(tekst) + strlen(drugi.tekst) + 1, drugi.tekst);      
    }

    char & operator[] (int position){
        char *pomocni = new char[strlen(tekst)+1];
        strcpy_s(pomocni, strlen(tekst) + 1, tekst);
        if (position <= strlen(tekst)){
            pomocni += position;
            pomocni--;
            return *pomocni;
        }
    }

    friend ostream & operator<< (ostream &COUT, FITString &obj);

};


ostream & operator<< (ostream &COUT, FITString &obj){
    COUT << obj.tekst;
    return COUT;
}

int main()
{
    FITString bezze = "Sta ima";
    FITString bezze2 = "Nema nista";
    FITString bezze3 = "Ma eo";
    FITString bezze4 = bezze + bezze2 + bezze3;
    cout << bezze4 << endl;
    FITString bezze5 = "Ma jok";
    cout << endl;

    bezze5 += bezze;
    cout << bezze5 << endl;
    cout << bezze5[4] << endl;
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `operator+=` you `strcat` without allocating extra space for the new chars.

Comment: Can you please post the whole program output and the error that you are getting?

Comment: _I am getting a run-time error_. Could you be more specific ?

Comment: OK, I 've understood what you mean by "runtime error". I suppose you've got this _Windows has triggered a breakpoint in testco.exe.



This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in testco.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.



This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while testco.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information._  This basically means you are trashing memory that is not yours, because of a buffer overflow or something similar.

Comment: Also, in `operator+` you allocate memory with `new` but never free it. Also, that function is supposed to return `FITString` but it returns a `char *`.

Comment: Thanks guys. Now I see where my memory leaks were.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your operator +=.
You are concatenating strings without allocating required amount of space.
Your function should look something like this:

```
void operator+= (FITString &drugi) {
    char *pomocna = new char[strlen(tekst) + strlen(drugi.tekst) + 1];
    strcpy_s(pomocna, strlen(tekst) + 1, tekst);
    strcat_s(pomocna, strlen(tekst) + strlen(drugi.tekst) + 1, drugi.tekst);
    delete[] tekst;
    tekst = pomocna;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I should add `delete[] pomocna` after `tekst = pomocna` . And I should probably do  my `FITString operator+ (FITString &drugi)` function the same way I did this one.

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't do `delete[] pomocna` after `tekst = pomocna`.
With `char *pomocna = new char[...]` you allocated new memory space, and with `delete[] tekst`; you deallocated old memory space.
`tekst = pomocna` is there so your `tekst` pointer will point to newly allocated space.

Comment: And for operator+ you sholud see @ramteid s answer

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a memory leak, there's one in `operator+`:  The last line (`return pomocna;`) returns a `char*` rather than a `FITString` as declared.  The compiler doesn't complain, because `FITString` has a 'conversion constructor' `FITString::FITString(char*)` it can use to create the needed `FITString` from the returned `char*` value.

Problem is, the implementation of `FITString::FITString(char*)` copies the passed string, so the `char* pomocna` allocated in `operator+` never gets deleted.

To avoid such confusing conversions is one reason I always declare all conversion constructors and conversion assignment operators as `explicit`.